# Is there a way of finding the turning point of a quadratic without calculus and without completing the square?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

Using completing the square it's trivial to find the minimum of a polynomial such as
$x^2+9x+5$. We rearrange to get $(x+\frac{9}{2})^2-\frac{61}{4}$ and can see that when $x=-\frac{9}{2}$ we have a minimum.

Using calculus it's also trivial. The derivative of $x^2+9x+5$ with respect to $x$ is $2x+9$, and the value of $x$ that makes $2x+9=0$ is $-\frac{9}{2}$.

My question is: are there any unusual methods to find the minimum of a quadratic (or, if possible, higher order polynomial)? Something not rooted in algebraic manipulation like completing the square or calculus?

Comment: Note that both all of your methods and all of the answers below point to the simple fact that the vertex of a parabola is *always* at $x=-b/2a$. Using the calculus method, for instance, $\frac{d}{dx} (ax^2 + bx+c) =2ax+b \implies V: 2ax+b=0 \implies x = -b/2a$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another way to look at it:  If the curve $y=ax^2+bx+c$ has two $x$-intercepts then the max/min happens at their average.  But we can slide the parabola up or down without changing the $x$-coordinate of the vertex.  So subtract off the constant term:

$$y=ax^2+bx = x(ax+b).$$

The two $x$-intercepts are $0$ and $-b/a$.  The vertex then, has $x$-coordinate $(0 + (-b/a))/2 = -b/2a..$

Answer (score 4):

You can "depress" a polynomial  $ax^n+bx^{n-1}+\cdots+c$ by substituting $x=y-b/na.$  The new polynomial in $y$ won't have an $x^{n-1}$ term.

If you do this for a quadratic, $ax^2+bx+c$, and let $x = y-b/2a$ the result has no linear term.  You get a quadratic of the form $ay^2+D$, which clearly has minimum/maximum at $y = 0$.  Put this back in the substitution to get $x = -b/2a.$

Comment: If you do this for a quadratic, then you are precisely completing the square. So I'm confused why this was accepted.

Comment: @Thissitehasbecomeadump.  The question seems to be "How many different ways can you find $x=-b/2a".  The different ways give different insights.  The fun part of mathematics is seeing how different things give you the same answer.  And yeah, it's a dump, but it's not as bad as sci.math became.

Comment: I agree @Thissitehasbecomeadump. This answer is possible copy of completing the square.

Comment: @User  _All_  the ways of doing this is the equivalent of completing the square.  The point of the question is to find different ways to apprehend the solution.

Comment: @B.Goddard  I am sorry, but this is not a different at all. Completing the square already uses $x\mapsto x-\frac {b}{2a}$. I think, this is an exact duplicate of the OP's attempt.

Comment: @User  Using the derivative is also the same thing.  It's a different viewpoint.  This solution ties in with the solution of the cubic, where other tacks don't.  Think about how you solve quadratic congruences modulo $p$.  Both the derivative and the discriminant appear there, but it's still completing the square.

Comment: @B.Goddard An obvious duplicate is often different from an answer that just leans on that method. Your answer (but not other answers) is a one-to-one copy of OP's explicit attempt. We first use $x-\frac {b}{2a}$ to complete the square. This is what the OP is already doing. Another answer uses discriminant, but this is clearly not an attempt to complete the square.

Comment: @User  You can keep ignoring my point as long as you please, but until you address it, you have nothing new to say.

Comment: Exactly how does this answer differ from the OP's attempt?  Doesn't the OP need the $\left(x-\frac {b}{2a}\right)$ expression when he/she applies the completion to the square?  Replacing numbers with letters is not a different perspective.

Comment: @User I told you.  Either read it or don't.  Stop bothering me in either case.

Answer (score 3):

Without completing the square:

---

Let,

$$x^2+9x+5=a,\,a\in\mathbb R.$$

Then we have:

$$x^2+9x+(5-a)=0$$

Then note that:

If $x\in\mathbb R$, then $\Delta_x=9^2-4(5-a)\geqslant 0$. This implies that, $\Delta_x=4a+61\geqslant 0$. This yields $a\geqslant-\frac{61}{4}$.

Finally, observe that if $\Delta_x=0$, then the mininum occurs when,

$$x_1=x_2=-\frac 92.$$

---

**Generalization of the method:**

Let,

$$
\begin{align}&ax^2+bx+c=M\\
\implies &ax^2+bx+(c-M)=0\\
&\Delta_x= b^2-4a(c-M)\geqslant 0\\
\implies &4aM≥-(b^2-4ac)\end{align}
$$

This tells us,

$$
\begin{align}
&M\geqslant -\frac {b^2-4ac}{4a},\;\, \text{if}\; a>0\\
&M\leqslant -\frac {b^2-4ac}{4a},\;\, \text{if}\; a<0\end{align}
$$

This also means that the minimum/maximum occurs when:

$$\Delta_x=0\quad\text{or}\quad x=-\frac {b}{2a}.$$

Comment: The answer is generalized.

Answer (score 1):

There's a rather trivial method of finding the x-value of the extremum of a quadratic. All you have to do is construct a 2x2 matrix with the quadratic as its minimal polynomial, and then take the average of its eigenvalues. Simple! Or you could create a sequence with the quadratic as its generating function, take the limit of the ratios of its successive terms, and also extend it to negative infinity and take the limit of those ratios, then take the average of those two limits.

There are also ways of using Physics formulas to find the vertex. You can derive $v(t) = at+v_0$ rather easily, and then you can use such methods as a geometric argument to derive $x(t)= \frac {at^2}2+v_0t+x_0$. So if $x(t)=x^2+9x+5$, then we can deduce that $a=2,v_0=9,x_0=5$. Then we need $t$ such that $v(t)=0$, i.e. $at+v_0=0$, which gives us $t=-\frac{v_0}a = -\frac 92$.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as @B.Goddard's answer, and uses the root formula (which assumes completion by square), so this is more of a comment than an answer.

If $r_-$ and $r_+$ are roots of the quadratic, because the quadratic is symmetric, the turning point will happen in the middle between them (the average).

The root formula is $r_\pm = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}\over 2a}$, and the average of these is
$$
{1\over2}\left({-b \color{red}{+ \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}\over 2a} + {-b \color{red}{-\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}\over 2a}\right) = -{b\over 2a}
$$